# Vuex: Having a problem using a getter inside a view

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have a module named 'tasks' in store which has this getter -

```
getTaskById: state => id => state.idToTask[id]
```

seems quite straightforward and basic, idToTask is just an object with ids as keys.

Now in the view (the component that displays the task) - it gets taskId as prop from router, I use mapGetters like this -

```
methods: {
...mapGetters('tasks', ['getTaskById'])
}
```

and I have a computed:

```
task() {
return this.getTaskById(this.taskId)
}
```

I really don't know what went wrong here but I get error of task being undefined (in the template) for some reason...

And I'll just say ahead that I've tried

```
this.$store.getters['tasks/getTaskById'](taskId)
```

but it does not seem to work as well...

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's working like this but try `return this.getTaskById()(this.taskId)`

Answer (score 1):

Disregard my comment, mapGetters should go in computed, not methods.

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters('tasks', ['getTaskById'])
}
```

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1136